# What is the correct way to configure proxy settings for Angular CLI dev server for PathLocationStrategy

Tags: angular, proxy

I have an Angular 6 app that I have switched from HashLocationStrategy to PathLocationStrategy to work more easily with another JS library. This works fine until I want to deep link or just Refresh. I have to navigate back to the root and then refresh. However I would like to have deep linking and the live update using the dev server via "ng serve" to work correctly.

I have found many references that this should work by performing the correct Path Rewrite in the proxy settings for the dev server. I have found several examples of how to setup Apache and even IIS for this. But none of these references tell what this configuration value should be for the default dev server. Here is the only thing that I found and it doesn't quite work. When the app reloads it incorrectly tries to get the main.js, polyfills.js, etc. at the end of the Angular route (ie localhost/path/deep/main.js when it should be localhost/main.js for these):

```
{
  "/": {
    "pathRewrite": {"^/(.+)": "/index.html"},
    "target": "http://localhost:5003",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
   }
}
```

Can someone point me to the right reference on how to configure the proxy so that it correctly rewrites back to index.html when using the dev server via ng serve?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5113) to get some ideas

Comment: @Vikas I had looked at that issue before. It wanders off into describing how to get things to run in different servers but never answers the question about how to get the Angular CLI dev server to work. At least, I couldn't find it when I read the thread the first time or when I just looked it over again.